# How to match one string by ignoring special character

Tags: javascript, solr

I am implementing a searching technique by autosuggest and solr.

I am getting a bunch of matching strings with special characters. For example, if I search for

```
jp
```

The returned strings include:

```
jp,
j p ,
j.p.,
j.p. nag,
j-p-naga
```

I need to highlight all strings contains "jp" by ignoring special characters.

expected output like :

"j-p-naga"---- "j-p" should highlight({span}j-p{/span}-naga

Comment: What is your code so far? What do you exactly try to highlight? ("all strings contains "jp" by ignoring special characters") Please improve your question by edit. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: my input string is "jp". then outputs are :
jp---highlight should be "jp"
j p--- highlight should be "j p"
j.p.--- highlight should be "j.p."
j.p. nag---- highlight should be "j.p"
j-p-naga--- highlight should be "j-p"

Comment: Restating your incomprehensible question is not a way to clarify. You need to find a clearer way of asking the question. Just asking it again is not an effective technique.

Answer (score 0):

You want to eliminate special characters? Use regular expressions:

```
function removeSpecials(str) {
  return str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
}

console.log('jp' === removeSpecials('j .$#@p#@'));
console.log('jp' === removeSpecials('j.p.,');
// Both true
```

Or maybe you want to check if a string contains the character `j` followed by `p` in *any location*?

```
function strHasJP(str) { return /[^j]*j[^p]*p.*/.test(str); }
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. For help on RegExp, go here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions .